# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable

Tags: android, gradle, aidl

I'm having issues while trying to build AIDL files in Windows. Android Studio throws out this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':cert4android:compileDebugAidl'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Arnym\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\Arnym\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out -IC:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\Arnym\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b3ae9796be0d1ad9cfd545c1245d9377\transformed\core-1.8.0\aidl -IC:\Users\Arnym\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b86d63b63776f409147ebf794d217683\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.1.1\aidl -dC:\Users\Arnym\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl4894162190838476317.d C:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\src\main\aidl\at\bitfire\cert4android\ICustomCertService.aidl}
```

However, if I run the command manually:

```
C:\Users\Arnym\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aidl.exe -pC:\Users\Arnym\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out -IC:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\Arnym\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b3ae9796be0d1ad9cfd545c1245d9377\transformed\core-1.8.0\aidl -IC:\Users\Arnym\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b86d63b63776f409147ebf794d217683\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.1.1\aidl -dC:\Users\Arnym\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl12302390005264781334.d C:\Users\Arnym\GitProjects\davx5-ose\cert4android\src\main\aidl\at\bitfire\cert4android\IOnCertificateDecision.aidl
```

It works correctly, doesn't throw any errors, and the interfaces get generated correctly.

Maybe Android Studio is interpreting the response code wrongly?

Android Studio:

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Beta 3
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9173235, built on October 13, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.balloon.shadow.size=0

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    detekt (1.21.3-android)
    com.intellij.marketplace (221.6008.18)
    com.github.patou.gitmoji (1.11.0)
    com.mallowigi (64.0.0)
    com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (7.5.4)
```

AGP `7.3.0`, and Gradle `7.4.2`. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you very much in advance.

**Edit:** As an extra note, this does indeed build in Linux. I've tried it on WSL and it works flawlessly. The issue is that using WSL for Android development is still a bit odd, and gives more problems than solutions.